# Soft keyboard pushes Navigation Bar off the view / screen in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a text field in bottom and navigation bar on the top of the view. When I focus on the text field navigation bar goes out of the screen.
I attach two images what happens.

[image]
[image] 
Help me to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out a solution. 
I change my AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
</activity>
```

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
This worked, The navigation bar of App doesn't disappear.

Comment: And what about IOS? I have the same problem there